# Pointer as an argument in function pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-pointers

Ok so I have a question.
How to make a **pointer as a argument inside a function pointer**?
I tried this:

```
void (*myFunction)(*myClass);
```

or

```
void (*myFunction)((*myClass));
```

But first return error:

> excepted identifier before * token

and second one same but with '('.
Any help appreciated.
Edit: its inside class definition (.h file).

Comment: I also tried void (*myFunction)(*(myClass));

Comment: downvotes are a bit harsh - i've always had problems with function pointer syntax even after 40 years using them

Comment: In this instance, the syntax is no different than it's ever been for a pointer to a type.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Why is it difficult to remember after 40 years: [Type * optional Name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer)?

Comment: @Type its the overall syntax not particularly pointer arguments - also, one typically, even across a long career, use ptfs somewhat infrequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

`void (*myFunction)(myClass*);`

When declaring a pointer for a variable or function parameter, you need to specify the *type* before the `*`, and the *name* after (in a function parameter, the name is optional).

So, a pointer to a type named `myClass` would be declared as `myClass*` rather than `*myClass`.

The reason the `*` appears before `myFunction` rather than after is because `myFunction` is a *name* not a *type*. You are declaring a variable named `myFunction` whose type is `void (*)(myClass*)`, ie a pointer to a function that returns nothing and takes in a `myClass*` pointer as a parameter.